# AWS Kinesis Firehose record data not readable

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to read Kinesis Firehose record data in transformation Lambda, but I'm getting some weird string ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMIDX.png)). Data coming to Firehose is VPC flow log. Destination for Firehose is S3 bucket and I'm able to change metadata of bucket object and actually read the logs, but I need to get readable data in lambda before it goes to S3. I tried various decodings, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Data from KinesisFirehoseEvent record is compressed, I needed to decompress it in order to read it.

Comment: Saved me hours. Thanks!